# copy paragraph from multiline texbox form to outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a form with a multiline texbox, when I write a paragraph and try to copy it to outlook just as It looks in texbox with the spaces between lines but it copy all the paragraph in one line. You can see it in the images. I know that I can write the paragraph in HTML code in .HTMLBody, but that's not what I want because I want to edit that anytime I send a mail. I don't know if there is a code to do that, if not could you give me some other ideas?

[Form_Enviar_Correo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXxkS.jpg)

[Outlook Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsVRl.jpg)

```
Sub ENVIAR()
Dim a As Worksheet, b As Worksheet
Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, sbdy As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ChDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path)

Dest = Form_Enviar_Correo.Txt_Para.Value
Asun = Form_Enviar_Correo.Txt_Asunto.Value
CC = Form_Enviar_Correo.Txt_CC.Value

Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

spie = "<img align=left width=80 height=90 src=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.png>" 

sbdy = spie

With OMail
    .To = Dest
    .CC = CC
    '.BCC = SCop
    .Subject = Asun
    .Body = Form_Enviar_Correo.Txt_Cuerpo.Text

    .HTMLBody = sbdy

    .Display
    '.Send
End With

Set OMail = Nothing
Set OApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'MsgBox ("El mensaje se envió con éxito"), vbInformation, "AVISO"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the lines are separated by a carriage return `vbCr` you can just replace them all with the HTML equivalent with one line of code using the `Replace` function.

```
Dim sText as String
sTest = "This is" & vbCr & "a test"
MsgBox sTest

Dim sHTMLFormat as String
sHTMLFormat = Replace(sTest, vbCr, "<br>")
MsgBox sHTMLFormat
```

so...

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(Form_Enviar_Correo.Txt_Cuerpo.Text, vbCr, "<br>")
```

They may also be separated by `vbNewLine` or `vbCrLf` or `vbLf` so use the one that works in your case.